# Why are my message be processed out of order over a single WCF TCP channel (with ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)?

Tags: wcf, multithreading, asynchronous

The client sends a lot of messages to the server from a single thread, over a single WCF channel.

The client sends the message with BeginMyMethod(x, b) as it does not wish to block while they get processed.

We have reliable messaging turned on, as we don’t wish to lose any messages, or have them get out of order.

However the messages are being despatched on multiple threads on the server, so are being process out of order.

We can’t have the server being single threaded, as we don’t wish a long running request from one client to block **other clients**.

So I just wish to process all the messages that come from a **single** client (over a **single channel**) in **order** with **only one** message from each cleint being processed at a time.

This would be easy for raw socket programming, however how to I get WCF to work as I wish?

---

I am now thinking that ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant does not behave well when used with InstanceContextMode.Single If I set use ConcurrencyMode.Single the messages are kept in order, but my call-backs deadlock.

(The test that gets the messages out of order has no callbacks and does not make any outgoing WCF calls, so I would expect ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant to behave the same as ConcurrencyMode.Single in that given test, but it does not)

I a not using any WCF config files, the code is:

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(this);
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
   typeof(IAllEngineManagersAsyncCallbacks),
   new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, true),
   endPointAddress);
```

Comment: What is a "chancel"? you used that word three times. Do you mean channel?

Comment: Are you able to post your custom binding configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have now worked round this problem by:

- Changing all my call-backs from the server to the client to be OneWay
- Using a dispatcher in the client before passing on any callback from the server, so client code never calls the sever from within a call-back

  - The client call-back object is marked with CallbackBehavior(**UseSynchronizationContext=false**, ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Single)
  - When running in Winform or WPF I use SynchronizationContext.**Post** to depatch the callbacks
  - When the cleint is a Console or a Windows server I use a [custom depatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319899/how-to-dispatch-work-items-to-a-single-thread).
- So letting me use ConcurrencyMode.Single  on both the server and the client.

It is now working as expected.
 (BeginMyMethod(x, b) is still being used to send messaged from the client to the server)

(ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant seems to sometimes release the lock even when the WCF call is not made on the some thread that is processing the incoming message, it is just not a useful as Reentrant was in DCOM)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the generated BeginXXX async-methods, these are executed on a ThreadPool thread.
So although you've send the messages in a defined order, nobody guarantees you in which order the ThreadPool executes the requests.

Comment: Can anyone else comfirm this?

Comment: We when first wrote this code we used myDelegate.BeginInvoke(a, b) and then called the wcf method from within the delegate. Our test failed ALL the time with messages getting out of order due to the queued ThreadPool requests. So the generated BeginXXX async-methods are doing something different.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Reentrant mode implies that you allow messages be processed out of order. Normal behavior of such service would be: get message, put in queue for internal threads to process, and when it's done notify client about result. So maybe your service get messages in proper order but some of them are quiker to process and return earlier than others?

Comment: as I understand it, Reentrant only lets in a new message when I make a outgoing wcf call.  The test case that fails does not make any outgoing calls.